# $f$ a continuous function, $f^{1/n}$ converges uniformly. How many zeros of $f$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, continuity

> *Let $f$ be a non-negative continuous function on the interval [0,1]. Suppose that the sequence $f^{1/n}$ converges uniformly. How many zeros does $f$ have?*

I'm confused about what this question is asking, since I don't think it is saying that $f^{1/n}$ converges to $f$. However, I feel like without that I do not have enough information to do anything... any help is appreciated!

Comment: $$\lim_{n\to\infty} f(x)^{1/n} = \begin{cases}0,& f(x) = 0\\1,& f(x) \ne 0\end{cases}$$ If the convergence is uniform, the final function is also continuous and...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Claim*: $a^{1/n}\to 1$ if $a>0$ and $a^{1/n}\to 0$ if $a=0$.